# In Vim, there is one line with 10000 characters, how can I select / replace / delete the characters between 1234th to 5678th fast?

Tags: vim, emacs, editor

There is one line with 10000 characters, how can I select / replace / delete the characters between 1234th to 5678th fast?
Better in Vim, but if emacs can do, it's also good, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

## With `:substitute`:

You can skip the first 1233 characters, and then capture 5678 - 1234 + 1 = 4445 characters, using the `:help /\{` multi, and `:help /\zs` to set the match start:

```
:substitute/^.\{1233}\zs.\{4445}/REPLACEMENT/
```

## Normal mode

Go to the first character (`0`, 1233 right, then work on the next 4445 via the `4445l` motion. For example, deletion: `01223ld4445l`.

## Direct addressing

The bad thing about both approaches is that you need to calculate the difference (4445 in your example). You can do that in the command-line via the expression register (`<C-r>=5678-1234+1<CR>`).

Alternatively, if there are no double-width or tab characters, the *screen column* can be directly addressed via the `:help /\%v` regular expression atom, or the `|` normal mode command:

```
:substitute/\%1234v.*\%5678v./REPLACEMENT/
```

or

```
1234|d5678|
```

Comment: @Meninx-メネンックス: Well, yes, if the long line is the first one, and if each character is represented by exactly one byte.

Answer (score 0):

In Emacs, navigate to the line and use `move-to-column` (bound to `M-g TAB` by default).  Use `set-mark-command` (`C-SPC`) to activate the region.  `M-g TAB 1234 RET C-SPC M-g TAB 5678 RET` will select the region of interest.  Then you can use `narrow-to-region` (`C-x n n`) to narrow the buffer to just the selected region.  Narrowing the buffer allows you to edit the narrowed region without affecting the rest.  After editing, you can widen with `widen` (`C-x n w`).